# java: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, swing

Я пытаюсь реализовать будильник, который будет работать с несколькими запросами одновременно.

Я сделал `JTabbledPane`, и при создании каждого `JPanel` попытался сделать инициализацию отдельного таймера, после которого воспроизведётся звук и Диалоговое окно с уведомлением о будильнике.

Но в `Timer` у меня выдает ошибку:

```
responseTime.(java: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final).
```

Как от этого избавиться и так, что бы при создании каждого нового `TabbledPane` был создан аналогичный работающий таймер я не знаю. Ниже этих слов в условиях `if`  у меня подчеркивает все `responseTime` красным, и как раз они выдают ошибку:

```
Timer buff = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (responseTime == null) return;
                        if (responseTime.before(new GregorianCalendar())) {
                            responseTime = null;
                            playSoundFromResourse("ding.wav");
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "ALARM", "ALARM", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Я бы хотел понять, как сделать все в таком виде, не меняя способ `JTabbledPane`. Возможно, проблема не только в этом, но и в потоках, в которых я еще не разобрался.

После картинки следуют полный код отрезка, где был реализован сам `JTabbledPane`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        bottomPanel.setVisible(true);

        Font font2 = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setFont(font2);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        bottomPanel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton add = new JButton("Add Alarm");
        add.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        add.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add.setFont(font2);
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                GregorianCalendar responseTime;
                JPanel buffPanel = new JPanel();
                buffPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                JTextField alarmHoursField = new JTextField();
                JTextField alarmMinutsField = new JTextField();
                alarmHoursField.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                alarmHoursField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 50, 10, 50));
                alarmHoursField.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                alarmMinutsField.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                alarmMinutsField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 50, 10, 50));
                alarmMinutsField.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

                JLabel information = new JLabel("Write Hours and Minutes");
                information.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
                information.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                JButton set = new JButton("SET");
                set.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                set.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                responseTime = new GregorianCalendar();

                set.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        hoursAlarm = parseInt(alarmHoursField.getText());
                        minuteAlarm = parseInt(alarmMinutsField.getText());

                        responseTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursAlarm);
                        responseTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteAlarm);
                        responseTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                        if (responseTime.before(new GregorianCalendar())) {
                            responseTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        }
                    }
                });
                Timer buff = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (responseTime == null) return;
                        if (responseTime.before(new GregorianCalendar())) {
                            responseTime = null;
                            playSoundFromResourse("ding.wav");
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "ALARM", "ALARM", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                });
                buffPanel.add(information);
                buffPanel.add(alarmHoursField);
                buffPanel.add(alarmMinutsField);
                buffPanel.add(set);
                tabbedPane.addTab("Alarm " + i++, buffPanel);

            }
        });
        buttons.add(add);

        JButton remove = new JButton("Delete Alarm");
        remove.setFont(font2);
        remove.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        remove.setForeground(Color.RED);
        remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int select = tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
                if (select >= 0) {
                    tabbedPane.removeTabAt(select);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        });
        buttons.add(remove);
        bottomPanel.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //add in content panel
        bottomPanel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: переменная  должна быть иммутабельная.

Answer (score 0):

Данная ошибка компилятора указывает, что при использовании локальной переменной (в данном случае `responseTime`) внутри вложенного класса значение такой переменной не может быть переприсвоено.  Однако, внутреннее состояние может быть изменено при помощи сеттеров.

В целом, основная проблема состоит в том, что значение `responseTime` требуется сбросить в `null`, чтобы звуковой файл был проигран только один раз.  Того же самого эффекта можно достичь, если просто прекратить действие таймера, вызвав его метод `stop`:

```java
Timer buff = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (responseTime.before(new GregorianCalendar())) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop(); // сразу же остановить таймер
            playSoundFromResourse("ding.wav");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainFrame.this, "ALARM", "ALARM", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
});
```

`buff.stop()` вызвать нельзя, так как инициализация переменной `buff` ещё не завершена.

Также в представленном коде следует вызвать метод `start` для экземпляра таймера, иначе он не запустится.